# Spring Transaction Management- Multiple request to same URL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-transactions

I am trying to create an API in Spring Boot using `@Transactional` annotation regarding bank fund transfer.

Now I want to know - if there are multiple calls to the same API at the same time, how to manage transaction between them. Suppose for example `transferBalance` method is called by Transaction `X` which transfers funds from accounts `A` to `B` and another transaction Transaction `Y` transfer funds from `B` to `C`. Both transactions occur at the same time. How would these transactions be handled? What propagation should it have and also what about the isolation?

Answer (score 4):

Check this below changes: for your case check bold description below.
**if more than one transaction can also go with SERIALIZED**

**Isolation level** defines how the changes made to some data repository by one transaction affect other simultaneous concurrent transactions, and also how and when that changed data becomes available to other transactions. When we define a transaction using the Spring framework we are also able to configure in which isolation level that same transaction will be executed.

```
@Transactional(isolation=Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
public void someTransactionalMethod(Object obj) {

}
```

READ_UNCOMMITTED isolation level states that a transaction may read data that is still uncommitted by other transactions.

**READ_COMMITTED isolation level states that a transaction can't read data that is not yet committed by other transactions.**

REPEATABLE_READ isolation level states that if a transaction reads one record from the database multiple times the result of all those reading operations must always be the same.

SERIALIZABLE isolation level is the most restrictive of all isolation levels. Transactions are executed with locking at all levels (read, range and write locking) so they appear as if they were executed in a serialized way.

Answer (score 0):

Your doubt has nothing to do with `@Transactional`.
Its simple question of concurrency. 
Actually both the transaction, form a to b and form b to c can work concurrently. 
By putting `@Transactional` states something like

> works out whether a given exception should cause transaction rollback by applying a number of rollback rules, both positive and negative. If no rules are relevant to the exception, it behaves like DefaultTransactionAttribute (rolling back on runtime exceptions).